# AspectJ - can't override pointcut - parameter types don't match

Tags: java, overriding, aop, aspectj, pointcut

I have an abstract aspect like this:

```
public abstract aspect GenericAspect<T> {

    public abstract T createT(Object[] args);

    abstract pointcut callMethod(Object[] args);

    T around(Object[] args) : callMethod(args) {
        return createT(args);
    }
}
```

And I would like to extend this aspect to another one abstract aspect that overrides only the abstract pointcut. Like the following example (where Foo is an interface):

```
public abstract aspect FooAspect extends GenericAspect<Foo> {

    pointcut callMethod(Object[] args):
        call(Foo *.*(..)) && args(args);
}
```

But I have this compile error:

> can't override pointcut GenericAspect.callMethod(java.lang.Object[]) with pointcut FooAspect.callMethod(java.lang.Object[]) parameter don't match

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know exactly why your example does not work, maybe there is a little bug in AspectJ or you have just made false assumptions concerning what is possible with AspectJ in combination with generics and abstract pointcuts. I suggest you ask the same question on the [AspectJ users mailing list](https://dev.eclipse.org/mailman/listinfo/aspectj-users).

In the meantime, would it be okay for you to do this, slightly modifying the syntax and moving the `args()` binding into the advice rather than into the pointcut?

**Driver application:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(new Application().createFoo());
  }

  public Foo createFoo(Object... args) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

**Helper class:**

```
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Foo {}
```

**Aspects:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

public abstract aspect GenericAspect<T> {
  public abstract T createT(Object[] args);

  abstract pointcut callMethod();

  T around(Object[] args): callMethod() && args(args) {
    return createT(args);
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import de.scrum_master.app.Foo;

public abstract aspect FooAspect extends GenericAspect<Foo> {
  pointcut callMethod():
    call(Foo *(..));
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import de.scrum_master.app.Foo;

public aspect ConcreteFooAspect extends FooAspect {
  @Override
  public Foo createT(Object[] args) {
    return new Foo();
  }
}
```

**Console log:**

```
de.scrum_master.app.Foo@511d50c0
```

Please note that the aspect kicks in, otherwise `null` would be printed here.

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me. Another possible variant is to fetch args from the around advice with `Object[] args = thisJoinPoint.getArgs();`

Comment: Well, but then it gets ugly because you need to iterate over the `Object[]` returned by `getArgs`. In your example, you would get your own `Object[]` as first method parameter via `Object[] methodArgs = (Object[])  thisJoinPoint.getArgs()[0];`. I prefer a more type-safe solution without casting. It also has the advantage of limiting pointcut matching to methods who really have a signature with exactly one `Object[]` parameter. Not using `args()` but just `getArgs()` means if-else, iterating, casting plus a lot of bytecode weaving in unneeded places.